# Producing random sets from a multiset

Tags: java, algorithm, random

I have N items, with duplicates:

```
List<Item> items;
```

I'd like to place them in m sized sets, in which all items must be distinct.

I tried using [Guava's Multiset](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset):

```
HashMultiset<Item> multiset = HashMultiset.create(items);
List<List<Item>> distribution = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<N/m;i++){
    Set<Item> unique = multiset.elementSet();
    List<Item> randomized = new ArrayList<>(unique);
    Collections.shuffle(randomized);
    List<Item> pack = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
        pack.add(randomized.get(j));
    }
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
        multiset.remove(randomized.get(j));
    }
    distribution.add(pack);
}
```

This method generates unique combination of items till the end, where no unique elements left to put in the last several packs. So it fails with array out of bounds exception.

I'm aware of that this algorithm can be revised to accept non-unique packs, however my question is how to produce fully unique distribution?

For a visual representation, here is an example list of items: (N=30, m=3)
A,A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,D,D,D,D,E,E,E,F,F,F,F,F,F,F

Achieved output: 
[A,B,F][B,D,F][B,D,F][A,D,E]...[F,F,C] (notice last one isn't internally unique)

Expected output:
[A,B,F][B,D,F][B,D,F][F,D,E]...[A,F,C]

Comment: Can you assume that there exists a feasible solution? What about the case `N=4`, `m=2`, input=`A, A, A, B`, which obviously has no solution? Moreover, how do you envision the distribution? Should each feasible solution have an equal chance of occurence?

Comment: I assume there exists at least one feasible solution for given inputs, and yes each feasible solution should have equal chance of occurance.